# Bootstrap Accordion doesn't work in React js

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have wanted to make an accordion for search section on my react js project. I have used the bootstrap accordion component. I have installed necessary packages with the commands "npm install bootstrap@latest --save" and "npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap" but it gives the below error.

[image]

Here is my code;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

const Search = ({ onSearch }) => {
    const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
    const [searchId, setSearchId] = useState('');
  
    const handleToggle = () => {
      setExpanded(!isExpanded);
    };
  
    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
      setSearchId(e.target.value);
    };
  
    const handleSearch = () => {
      if (onSearch) {
        onSearch(searchId);
      }
    };
  

  return (
    <>
    <Accordion>
    <Card>
      <Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0" onClick={handleToggle}>
          {isExpanded ? 'Hide Search' : 'Show Search'}
        </Accordion.Toggle>
      </Card.Header>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
        <Card.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="formSearchId">
              <Form.Label>Search ID:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter ID"
                value={searchId}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSearch}>
              Search
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Card>
  </Accordion>
    </>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

And I have imported this like `import Search from './Search';` on parent component. How can I fix the error?

I also have tried to use the bootstrap by adding it into classes, it worked but when i do it as in the code (what i mean is components) it doesn't work.